# How to predict the original data given a corrupted dataset?

Tags: r, replace, na, predict, imputation

Lets say, users can choose to enter 0s or just leave it blank(NA) on the client side, but the system changes those NA ,that some users left blank, to 0s when they reach our database.

How to predict or impute the corrupted data in order to reset those 0s to NA correctly?

PS:
The new system does not change the value so my boss expect me to predict/impute old corrupted data correctly given the new data...

I've tired MICE, KKN, PCA methods for imputation but those only change the data into other numbers instead of NAs. Is there any way to do this?

imputed data:

```
 0.0015 0.0252   0.0159  0.0116 -0.0431 0.0252  -0.0058
-0.0955 0.0373   0.0437  0.0342  0.0348 0.0412  -0.0650
-0.1685 0.1113  -0.0399 -0.1207 -0.0243 0.1190   0.0300
```

For example some values from new dataset:

```
 0.0015 0.0252   0.0159 0.0116  -0.0431 NA      -0.0058 
-0.0955 0.0373   0.0437 0        0.0348 0.0412  -0.065
-0.1685 0.1113  -0.0399 -0.1207 -0.0243 0.1190       NA
```

And the old values could be like this:(im just making it simple now, the old data is a completely different one from the new ones with tons of 0s and no NA)

```
 0.0015 0.0252   0.0159  0.0116 -0.0431 0       -0.0058 
-0.0955 0.0373   0.0437  0.0036  0.0348 0.0412  -0.065
-0.1685 0.1113  -0.0399 -0.1207 -0.0243 0.1190   0
```

My boss expect me to impute the the old data to new data, not replacing 0 values to some predicted numbers generated by different models but replace them to NA.

Comment: Question is not very clear. Do you just want to convert 0 values to NA ?

Comment: Yes, but only the part of 0s that is originally NA

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace all `0s` with `NAs` you can do this via

```
df[df == 0] <- NA
```

But this would of course also mean, that you are replacing the values that originally were 0. As you describe it, there is no way to prevent this. You would have to get hold of a original dataset (before your database automatically changes the NAs to 0s) to do this.